# Pyspark groupby then sort within group

Tags: group-by, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table which contains id, offset, text. Suppose input:

```
id offset text
1  1      hello 
1  7      world
2  1      foo
```

I want output like:

```
id text
1  hello world
2  foo
```

I'm using:

```
df.groupby(id).agg(concat_ws("",collect_list(text))
```

But I don't know how to ensure the order in the text. I did `sort` before `groupby` the data, but I've heard that `groupby` might shuffle the data. Is there a way to do `sort` within group after `groupby` data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [collect\_list by preserving order based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable)

Answer (score 1):

this will create a required df:

```
df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame([("1", "1","hello"), ("1", "7","world"), ("2", "1","foo")], ("id", "offset" ,"text" ))
display(df1)
```

then you can use the following code, could be optimized further:

```
@udf
def sort_by_offset(col):
  result =""
  text_list = col.split("-")
  for i in range(len(text_list)):
    text_list[i] = text_list[i].split(" ")
    text_list[i][0]=int(text_list[i][0])
  text_list = sorted(text_list, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=False)
  for i in range(len(text_list)):
    result = result+ " " +text_list[i][1]
  return result.lstrip()
df2 = df1.withColumn("offset_text",concat(col("offset"),lit(" "),col("text")))
df3 = df2.groupby(col("id")).agg(concat_ws("-",collect_list(col("offset_text"))).alias("offset_text"))
df4 = df3.withColumn("text",sort_by_offset(col("offset_text")))
display(df4)
```

Final Output:
[image: Final Output]

Answer (score 0):

Add `sort_array`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sort_array

df.groupby(id).agg(concat_ws("", sort_array(collect_list(text))))
```

Comment: This won't work, my sort key is offset, not string itself.