# collect_list by preserving order based on another variable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to create a new column of lists in Pyspark using a groupby aggregation on existing set of columns. An example input data frame is provided below:

```
------------------------
id | date        | value
------------------------
1  |2014-01-03   | 10 
1  |2014-01-04   | 5
1  |2014-01-05   | 15
1  |2014-01-06   | 20
2  |2014-02-10   | 100   
2  |2014-03-11   | 500
2  |2014-04-15   | 1500
```

The expected output is:

```
id | value_list
------------------------
1  | [10, 5, 15, 20]
2  | [100, 500, 1500]
```

The values within a list are sorted by the date.

I tried using collect_list as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ordered_df = input_df.orderBy(['id','date'],ascending = True)
grouped_df = ordered_df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_list("value"))
```

But collect_list doesn't guarantee order even if I sort the input data frame by date before aggregation.

Could someone help on how to do aggregation by preserving the order based on a second (date) variable?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

EDIT: `pyspark.sql.functions.array_sort` was added in PySpark 2.4, which operates exactly the same as the `sorter` UDF defined below and will generally be more performant. Leaving the old answer for posterity.

**For PySpark <2.4 only:**

If you collect both dates and values as a list, you can sort the resulting column according to date using and `udf`, and then keep only the values in the result.

```
import operator
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# create list column
grouped_df = input_df.groupby("id") \
               .agg(F.collect_list(F.struct("date", "value")) \
               .alias("list_col"))

# define udf
def sorter(l):
  res = sorted(l, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
  return [item[1] for item in res]

sort_udf = F.udf(sorter)

# test
grouped_df.select("id", sort_udf("list_col") \
  .alias("sorted_list")) \
  .show(truncate = False)
+---+----------------+
|id |sorted_list     |
+---+----------------+
|1  |[10, 5, 15, 20] |
|2  |[100, 500, 1500]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example...I just tried it on a bigger data of a few millions and I am getting the exact same sequence as that of collect_list...Is there a way to explain why this could be happening? Also, checked that collect_list only seems to mess up those cases with multiple values within a date...Does it mean collect_list also maintains the order?

Comment: In your code, you sort the entire dataset before collect_list() so yes. But this is not necessary, it is more efficient to sort the resulting list of tuples after collecting both date and value in a list.

Comment: Just to clarify...sorting the column and using collect_list on the sorted column would preserve the order?

Comment: Depends how your data is partitioned accross the nodes, but the udf method should always guarantee correct order though because we sort per row.

Comment: Can you shed some light on how partitioning affects the result in the first case? In my case, all the million+ records have the same sequence between the two methods. I didn't specify any special partitioning.

Comment: Order in distributed systems is often meaningless, so correct order cannot be guaranteed unless the values for each id are in one partition.

Comment: Is there a way to figure out how the data is partitioned?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sort_udf = F.udf(sorter, ArrayType(IntegerType()))` given that `udf` uses `StringType` as the default return type if not specified, and `sorter` returns a list of integers?

Comment: this fails if we use `collect_set`

Comment: This answer is rather old by now, I think with the introduction of `array_sort` as the other answers describe, that is the best approach as it doesn't require the overhead of a UDF.

Answer (score 139):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')

sorted_list_df = input_df.withColumn(
            'sorted_list', F.collect_list('value').over(w)
        )\
        .groupBy('id')\
        .agg(F.max('sorted_list').alias('sorted_list'))
```

`Window` examples provided by users often don't really explain what is going on so let me dissect it for you.

As you know, using `collect_list` together with `groupBy` will result in an **unordered** list of values. This is because depending on how your data is partitioned, Spark will append values to your list as soon as it finds a row in the group. The order then depends on how Spark plans your aggregation over the executors.

A `Window` function allows you to control that situation, grouping rows by a certain value so you can perform an operation `over` each of the resultant groups:

```
w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date')
```

- `partitionBy` - you want groups/partitions of rows with the same `id`
- `orderBy` - you want each row in the group to be sorted by `date`

Once you have defined the scope of your Window - "rows with the same `id`, sorted by `date`" -, you can use it to perform an operation over it, in this case, a `collect_list`:

```
F.collect_list('value').over(w)
```

At this point you created a new column `sorted_list` with an ordered list of values, sorted by date, but you still have duplicated rows per `id`. To trim out the duplicated rows you want to `groupBy` `id` and keep the `max` value in for each group:

```
.groupBy('id')\
.agg(F.max('sorted_list').alias('sorted_list'))
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer due to the usage of Spark-basic functions - Very nice!

Comment: How does `max` work in this context where the values are arrays?

Comment: @nciao do you mean on a `ArrayType<ArrayType<*>>` column? My guess is exactly the same way as in a `ArrayType<*>`, as `max` by documentation _"returns the maximum value of the expression in a group"_.

Comment: I meant on the Sorted_List column, which would be of type ArrayType<int>. (my understanding is that you’re telling spark to aggregate the group, by taking the maximum value of that particular array in each group).

Comment: which led me to wonder “well, what is “max” for an array<int>?  or array<string>? “ (in my particular case)

Comment: The max is needed, because for the same "id", a list is created for each row, in the sorted order: [10], then [10, 5], then [10, 5, 15], then [10, 5, 15, 20] for id=1. Taking the max of lists takes the longest one (here [10, 5, 15, 20]).

Comment: What are the memory implications of this? Is this approach better than the accepted answer when we are dealing with chaining of billion+ events when a chain can have up to 10.000 items in collected list?

Comment: Doesn't this expansive ? If I have 10 million group , each group have 24 element . `F.collect_list('value').over(w)` would create a new column size from 1 to 24 , 10million * 24 times .   Then do another group by just get larget row from each group.

Comment: This doesn't work if you're using `collect_set` instead of `collect_list`.

Comment: This doesn't seem feasible if a single id has large numbers of rows. If id=1 has n rows of say long data types, then before the groupby you'll need to store (n^2)/2 longs, e.g., if n=10**7 then you'll need 400 terabytes for that column alone, and if n=10**8 you'd need 40 petabytes, etc

Answer (score 74):

You can use `sort_array` function. If you collect both dates and values as a list, you can sort the resulting column using `sort_array` and keep only the columns you require.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

grouped_df = (
    input_df
    .groupby("id")
    .agg(
        F.sort_array(F.collect_list(F.struct("date", "value")))
        .alias("collected_list")
    )
    .withColumn("sorted_list", F.col("collected_list.value"))
    .drop("collected_list")
).show(truncate=False)

+---+----------------+
|id |sorted_list     |
+---+----------------+
|1  |[10, 5, 15, 20] |
|2  |[100, 500, 1500]|
+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I find the Window.patitionBy and then get max row cannot perform on large data. Your solution is ~200 times faster.

Comment: Yes, this is way faster in scala as well: grouped_df = input_df.groupBy("id").agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct("date", "value"))).alias("collected_list")).withColumn("sorted_list", col("collected_list.value")) .drop("collected_list")

Comment: I didn't know Spark understands this notion collected_list.value as an array of corresponding field values. Nice!

Answer (score 22):

The question was for PySpark but might be helpful to have it also for Scala Spark.

## Let's prepare test dataframe:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.{ Window, UserDefinedFunction}

import java.sql.Date
import java.time.LocalDate

val spark: SparkSession = ...

// Out test data set
val data: Seq[(Int, Date, Int)] = Seq(
  (1, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-01-03")), 10),
  (1, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-01-04")), 5),
  (1, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-01-05")), 15),
  (1, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-01-06")), 20),
  (2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-02-10")), 100),
  (2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-02-11")), 500),
  (2, Date.valueOf(LocalDate.parse("2014-02-15")), 1500)
)

// Create dataframe
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(data)
  .toDF("id", "date", "value")
df.show()
//+---+----------+-----+
//| id|      date|value|
//+---+----------+-----+
//|  1|2014-01-03|   10|
//|  1|2014-01-04|    5|
//|  1|2014-01-05|   15|
//|  1|2014-01-06|   20|
//|  2|2014-02-10|  100|
//|  2|2014-02-11|  500|
//|  2|2014-02-15| 1500|
//+---+----------+-----+
```

## Use UDF

```
// Group by id and aggregate date and value to new column date_value
val grouped = df.groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(collect_list(struct("date", "value")) as "date_value")
grouped.show()
grouped.printSchema()
// +---+--------------------+
// | id|          date_value|
// +---+--------------------+
// |  1|[[2014-01-03,10],...|
// |  2|[[2014-02-10,100]...|
// +---+--------------------+

// udf to extract data from Row, sort by needed column (date) and return value
val sortUdf: UserDefinedFunction = udf((rows: Seq[Row]) => {
  rows.map { case Row(date: Date, value: Int) => (date, value) }
    .sortBy { case (date, value) => date }
    .map { case (date, value) => value }
})

// Select id and value_list
val r1 = grouped.select(col("id"), sortUdf(col("date_value")).alias("value_list"))
r1.show()
// +---+----------------+
// | id|      value_list|
// +---+----------------+
// |  1| [10, 5, 15, 20]|
// |  2|[100, 500, 1500]|
// +---+----------------+
```

## Use Window

```
val window = Window.partitionBy(col("id")).orderBy(col("date"))
val sortedDf = df.withColumn("values_sorted_by_date", collect_list("value").over(window))
sortedDf.show()
//+---+----------+-----+---------------------+
//| id|      date|value|values_sorted_by_date|
//+---+----------+-----+---------------------+
//|  1|2014-01-03|   10|                 [10]|
//|  1|2014-01-04|    5|              [10, 5]|
//|  1|2014-01-05|   15|          [10, 5, 15]|
//|  1|2014-01-06|   20|      [10, 5, 15, 20]|
//|  2|2014-02-10|  100|                [100]|
//|  2|2014-02-11|  500|           [100, 500]|
//|  2|2014-02-15| 1500|     [100, 500, 1500]|
//+---+----------+-----+---------------------+

val r2 = sortedDf.groupBy(col("id"))
  .agg(max("values_sorted_by_date").as("value_list")) 
r2.show()
//+---+----------------+
//| id|      value_list|
//+---+----------------+
//|  1| [10, 5, 15, 20]|
//|  2|[100, 500, 1500]|
//+---+----------------+
```

Comment: is it possible to accomplish this without either a window or udf via combination of explode, group by, order by?

Answer (score 7):

To make sure the sort is done for each id, we can use sortWithinPartitions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
ordered_df = (
    input_df
        .repartition(input_df.id)
        .sortWithinPartitions(['date'])


)
grouped_df = ordered_df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_list("value"))
```

Comment: The group by step is happening after the sort. Will the sort order be retained in group by step? There is no such guarantee AFAIK

Answer (score 5):

In the Spark SQL world the answer to this would be:

```
SELECT 
browser, max(list)
from (
  SELECT
    id,
    COLLECT_LIST(value) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) as list
  FROM browser_count
  GROUP BYid, value, date) 
Group by browser;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried TMichel approach and didn't work for me. When I performed the max aggregation I wasn't getting back the highest value of the list. So what worked for me is the following:

```
def max_n_values(df, key, col_name, number):
    '''
    Returns the max n values of a spark dataframe
    partitioned by the key and ranked by the col_name
    '''
    w2 = Window.partitionBy(key).orderBy(f.col(col_name).desc())
    output = df.select('*',
                       f.row_number().over(w2).alias('rank')).filter(
                           f.col('rank') <= number).drop('rank')
    return output

def col_list(df, key, col_to_collect, name, score):
    w = Window.partitionBy(key).orderBy(f.col(score).desc())

    list_df = df.withColumn(name, f.collect_set(col_to_collect).over(w))
    size_df = list_df.withColumn('size', f.size(name))
    output = max_n_values(df=size_df,
                               key=key,
                               col_name='size',
                               number=1)
    return output
```

Comment: I think it can be useful a little explanation how this works for you and the difference with the accepted answer

Comment: When I tried Tmichel's approach the max value didn't work. I wasn't getting back the list with the most elements, I was getting back random lists. So what I did is I created a new column which measures the size and got the highest values of eahc partition. Hope that make sense!

Answer (score 2):

As of Spark 2.4, the collect_list(ArrayType) created in @mtoto's answer can be post-processed by using SparkSQL's builtin functions [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [array_sort](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_sort) (no need for udf):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, expr, struct

df.groupby('id') \
  .agg(collect_list(struct('date','value')).alias('value_list')) \
  .withColumn('value_list', expr('transform(array_sort(value_list), x -> x.value)')) \
  .show()
+---+----------------+
| id|      value_list|
+---+----------------+
|  1| [10, 5, 15, 20]|
|  2|[100, 500, 1500]|
+---+----------------+
```

**Note:** if descending order is required change `array_sort(value_list)` to `sort_array(value_list, False)`

**Caveat:** array_sort() and sort_array() won't work if items(in collect_list) must be sorted by multiple fields(columns) in a mixed order, i.e. `orderBy('col1', desc('col2'))`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use spark sql here is how you can achieve this. Assuming the table name (or temporary view) is `temp_table`.

```
select
t1.id,
collect_list(value) as value_list
(Select * from temp_table order by id,date) t1
group by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementing what [ShadyStego](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4255302/shadystego) said, I've been testing the usage of sortWithinPartitions and GroupBy on Spark, finding out it performs quite better than Window functions or UDF. Still, there is an issue with a missordering once per partition when using this method, but it can be easily solved. I show it here [Spark (pySpark) groupBy misordering first element on collect_list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57255819/spark-pyspark-groupby-misordering-first-element-on-collect-list/57592754#57592754).

This method is specially useful on large DataFrames, but a large number of partitions may be needed if you are short on driver memory.