# Applying UDF while Joining two Spark dataframes with intervals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with three columns: `id`, `index` and `value`.

```
+---+-----+-------------------+
| id|index|              value|
+---+-----+-------------------+
|  A| 1023|0.09938822262205915|
|  A| 1046| 0.3110047630613805|
|  A| 1069| 0.8486710971453512|
+---+-----+-------------------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- index: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- value: double (nullable = false)
```

Then, I have another dataframe which shows desirable periods for each `id`:

```
+---+-----------+---------+
| id|start_index|end_index|
+---+-----------+---------+
|  A|       1069|     1276|
|  B|       2066|     2291|
|  B|       1616|     1841|
|  C|       3716|     3932|
+---+-----------+---------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- start_index: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- end_index: integer (nullable = false)
```

I have three templates as below

```
val template1 = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.42, 0.51, 0.61, 0.7)
val template2 = Array(0.96, 0.89, 0.82, 0.76, 0.71, 0.65, 0.57, 0.51, 0.41, 0.35)
val template3 = Array(0.0, 0.07, 0.21, 0.41, 0.53, 0.42, 0.34, 0.25, 0.19, 0.06)
```

The goal is, for each row in `dfIntervals`, apply a function (let's assume it's correlation) in which the function receives `value` column from `dfRaw` and three template arrays and adds three columns to `dfIntervals`, each column related to each template.

Assumptions:
1 - Sizes of templates arrays are are exactly 10.

2 - There are no duplicates in `index` column of `dfRaw`

3 - `start_index` and `end_index` columns in `dfIntervals` exist in `index` column of `dfRaw` and when there are exactly 10 rows between them. For instance, `dfRaw.filter($"id" === "A").filter($"index" >= 1069 && $"index" <= 1276).count` (first row in dfIntervals) results in exactly `10`.

Here's the code that generates these dataframes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val mySeed = 1000

/* Defining templates for correlation analysis*/
val template1 = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.42, 0.51, 0.61, 0.7)
val template2 = Array(0.96, 0.89, 0.82, 0.76, 0.71, 0.65, 0.57, 0.51, 0.41, 0.35)
val template3 = Array(0.0, 0.07, 0.21, 0.41, 0.53, 0.42, 0.34, 0.25, 0.19, 0.06)

/* Defining raw data*/
var dfRaw = Seq(
  ("A", (1023 to 1603 by 23).toArray),
  ("B", (341 to 2300 by 25).toArray),
  ("C", (2756 to 3954 by 24).toArray)
).toDF("id", "index")
dfRaw = dfRaw.select($"id", explode($"index") as "index").withColumn("value", rand(seed=mySeed))

/* Defining intervals*/
var dfIntervals = Seq(
  ("A", 1069, 1276),
  ("B", 2066, 2291),
  ("B", 1616, 1841),
  ("C", 3716, 3932)
).toDF("id", "start_index", "end_index")
```

There result is three columns added to `dfIntervals` dataframe with names `corr_w_template1`, `corr_w_template2` and `corr_w_template3`

PS: I could not find a correlation function in Scala. Let's assume such a function exists (as below) and we are about to make a `udf` out of it is needed.

```
def correlation(arr1: Array[Double], arr2: Array[Double]): Double
```

Comment: As I understand, You need a udf as following:
`def correlation(value: Double, template: Array[Double]): Double`
where `template` can be one of these values: `template1`, `template2`, `template3`. And `value` is from `dfRaw` . Right?

Comment: That's correct. The functions needs to be applied three times I suppose to get the correlation between the raw signal and each of the templates.

Comment: `dfIntervals` contains `start_index` & `end_index` So it should be 
`correlation(values: Array[Double], template: Array[Double]): Double` right?
Where `values` is obtained from dfRaw which has `index` in the range [start_index: end_index]

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.

Let's define a UDF function.

For testing purpose, let'say it will always return 1.

```
 val correlation = functions.udf( (values: mutable.WrappedArray[Double], template: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => {

     1f
  })

val orderUdf = udf((values: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) => {
    values.sortBy(r => r.getAs[Int](0)).map(r => r.getAs[Double](1))
  })
```

Then let's join your 2 data frames with the defined rules & collect `value` into 1 column called `values`. Also, apply our `orderUdf`

```
 val df = dfIntervals.join(dfRaw,dfIntervals("id") === dfRaw("id") && dfIntervals("start_index")  <= dfRaw("index") && dfRaw("index") <= dfIntervals("end_index") )
    .groupBy(dfIntervals("id"), dfIntervals("start_index"),  dfIntervals("end_index"))
    .agg(orderUdf(collect_list(struct(dfRaw("index"), dfRaw("value")))).as("values"))
```

Finally, apply our udf & show it out.

```
df.withColumn("corr_w_template1",correlation(df("values"), lit(template1)))
    .withColumn("corr_w_template2",correlation(df("values"), lit(template2)))
    .withColumn("corr_w_template3",correlation(df("values"), lit(template3)))
    .show(10)
```

This is full of example code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("learning").setMaster("local[2]")

  val session = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()



  val mySeed = 1000

  /* Defining templates for correlation analysis*/
  val template1 = Array(0.0, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.3, 0.33, 0.42, 0.51, 0.61, 0.7)
  val template2 = Array(0.96, 0.89, 0.82, 0.76, 0.71, 0.65, 0.57, 0.51, 0.41, 0.35)
  val template3 = Array(0.0, 0.07, 0.21, 0.41, 0.53, 0.42, 0.34, 0.25, 0.19, 0.06)

  val schema1 =  DataTypes.createStructType(Array(
    DataTypes.createStructField("id",DataTypes.StringType,false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("index",DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.IntegerType),false)
  ))

  val schema2 =  DataTypes.createStructType(Array(
    DataTypes.createStructField("id",DataTypes.StringType,false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("start_index",DataTypes.IntegerType,false),
    DataTypes.createStructField("end_index",DataTypes.IntegerType,false)
  ))

  /* Defining raw data*/
  var dfRaw = session.createDataFrame(Seq(
    ("A", (1023 to 1603 by 23).toArray),
    ("B", (341 to 2300 by 25).toArray),
    ("C", (2756 to 3954 by 24).toArray)
  ).map(r => Row(r._1 , r._2)).asJava, schema1)

  dfRaw = dfRaw.select(dfRaw("id"), explode(dfRaw("index")) as "index")
    .withColumn("value", rand(seed=mySeed))

  /* Defining intervals*/
  var dfIntervals =  session.createDataFrame(Seq(
    ("A", 1069, 1276),
    ("B", 2066, 2291),
    ("B", 1616, 1841),
    ("C", 3716, 3932)
  ).map(r => Row(r._1 , r._2,r._3)).asJava, schema2)

  //Define udf

  val correlation = functions.udf( (values: mutable.WrappedArray[Double], template: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]) => {
     1f
  })

  val orderUdf = udf((values: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) => {
    values.sortBy(r => r.getAs[Int](0)).map(r => r.getAs[Double](1))
  })


  val df = dfIntervals.join(dfRaw,dfIntervals("id") === dfRaw("id") && dfIntervals("start_index")  <= dfRaw("index") && dfRaw("index") <= dfIntervals("end_index") )
    .groupBy(dfIntervals("id"), dfIntervals("start_index"),  dfIntervals("end_index"))
    .agg(orderUdf(collect_list(struct(dfRaw("index"), dfRaw("value")))).as("values"))

  df.withColumn("corr_w_template1",correlation(df("values"), lit(template1)))
    .withColumn("corr_w_template2",correlation(df("values"), lit(template2)))
    .withColumn("corr_w_template3",correlation(df("values"), lit(template3)))
    .show(10,false)
```

Comment: I think that `dfRaw("id") === dfIntervals("id")` should be added to the join conditions to be `dfIntervals.join(dfRaw, dfIntervals("start_index") <= dfRaw("index") && dfRaw("index") <= dfIntervals( "end_index") && dfRaw("id") === dfIntervals("id"))` Otherwise, there will be contamination from other ids. when we do that, values order get reversed! We need to include `index`Win `collect_list` and use a sorter udf to make sure the values in the list are in order. Scala version of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: yeah. That's my mistake. I have updated the solution

Comment: Great. Thanks for the update. Is there a way to make sure `values` column is already ordered in `df`? While this can be done inside `udf` function, it would be cleaner to do it that way similar to [this Python solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: I meant to order the values based on index. Currently it is sorted based on values! Perhaps using `collect_list(struct(dfRaw("index"),dfRaw("value"))` and then using a map something along `(key, xs) => (key, xs.map(_.c2).toSeq.sortBy(_._2)))` will do that?

Comment: Yes. it's great

Comment: check it out again please