# Order is not preserved in PySpark collect_set only for string column

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, cloudera, window-functions

I am using the collect_set method on a DataFrame and adding 3 columns.

My df is as below:

```
id  acc_no  acc_name  cust_id    
1    111      ABC       88    
1    222      XYZ       99
```

Below is the code snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('acc_no')
df1 = df.withColumn(
    'cust_id_new',
    F.collect_set(cust_id).over(w)
).withColumn(
    'acc_no_new',
    F.collect_set(acc_no).over(w)
).withColumn(
    'acc_name_new',
    F.collect_set(acc_name).over(w)
).drop('cust_id').drop('acc_no').drop('acc_name')
```

In this case, my output is as follows:

```
id    acc_no     acc_name    cust_id   
1    [111,222]  [XYZ,ABC]    [88,99]
```

**So here, the acc_no and cust_id are correct, but the order of acc_name is incorrect.
acc_no 111 corresponds to acc_name ABC, but we are getting XYZ.**

Can someone please let me know why this is happening and what would be the solution ?

I suspect this issue is occurring for string column only, but i might be wrong.
Please help...

This is similar to below thread, but I am still getting an error.

[How to maintain sort order in PySpark collect_list and collect multiple lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199996/how-to-maintain-sort-order-in-pyspark-collect-list-and-collect-multiple-lists/58588904#58588904)

Comment: `set`'s are unordered in nature

Comment: what version of pyspark? in 2.4+ you might be able to use use `collect_list` with [`array_distinct`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_distinct). Or zip the arrays before sorting.

Comment: I am using spark 2.3.

Comment: 1 thing I would like to mention here is I have typecasted all the columns to string for a specific reason.

Answer (score 0):

We can use row_number function within the id column and use collect_list & sorted_array to preserve the order.

``````
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

w = Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('cust_id')
df1 = df.withColumn(
    'rn',
    row_number(cust_id).over(w)
).groupBy("id").agg(sort_array(collect_list(struct('rn','acc_no','acc_name','cust_id'))).alias('data')) \
.withColumn('grp_acc_no',col('data.acc_no')) \
.withColumn('grp_acc_name',col('data.acc_name')) \
.withColumn('grp_cust_id',col('data.cust_id')) \
.drop('data','acc_no','acc_name','cust_id').show(truncate=False) `````
``````