# Create LineString from Lat/Lon columns using PySpark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, shapely

I have a PySpark dataframe containing Lat/Lon points for different trajectories identified by a column "trajectories_id".

| trajectory_id | latitude | longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 | 5 |
| 1 | 45 | 6 |
| 1 | 45 | 7 |
| 2 | 46 | 5 |
| 2 | 46 | 6 |
| 2 | 46 | 7 |

What I want to do is to extract for each trajectory_id a LineString and store it in another dataframe, where each row represents a trajectory with "id" and "geometry" columns. In this example, the output should be:

| trajectory_id | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LINESTRING (5 45, 6 45, 7 45) |
| 2 | LINESTRING (5 46, 6 46, 7 46) |

This is similar to what has been asked in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202190/turning-geodataframe-of-x-y-coordinates-into-linestrings-using-groupby), but in my case I need to use PySpark.

I have tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point,LineString
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 45,5], [1, 45,6], [1, 45,7],[2, 46,5], [2, 46,6], [2, 46,7]], columns=['trajectory_id', 'latitude','longitude'])
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df)
idx_ = df1.select("trajectory_id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).distinct().collect()
geo_df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(idx_)),columns=['geometry','trajectory_id'])
k=0
for i in idx_:
    df2=df1.filter(F.col("trajectory_id").isin(i)).toPandas()
    df2['points']=df2[["longitude", "latitude"]].apply(Point, axis=1)
    geo_df.geometry.iloc[k]=str(LineString(df2['points']))
    geo_df['trajectory_id'].iloc[k]=i
    k=k+1
```

This code works, but as in my task I am working with many more trajectories (> 2milions), this takes forever as I am converting to Pandas in each iteration.
Is there a way I can obtain the same output in a more efficient way?
As mentioned, I know that using toPandas() (and/or collect() ) is something I should avoid, especially inside a for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using pyspark SQL's native functions.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

long_lat_df = df.withColumn('joined_long_lat', func.concat(func.col("longitude"), func.lit(" "), func.col("latitude")));

grouped_df = long_lat_df .groupby('trajectory_id').agg(func.collect_list('joined_long_lat').alias("geometry"))

final_df = grouped_df.withColumn('geometry', func.concat_ws(", ", func.col("geometry")));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The linestring will be ordered as per trajectories in the table.**

Changing a bit of Drashti's snippet as it doesn't completely convert the set of points to linestring. Apache Sedona installation is necessary.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

long_lat_df = result.withColumn('joined_long_lat', func.concat(func.col("longitude"), func.lit(","), func.col("latitude")));

grouped_df = long_lat_df.groupby('trajectory_id').agg(func.collect_list('joined_long_lat').alias("geometry"))

final_df = grouped_df.withColumn('geometry', func.concat_ws(",", func.col("geometry")))

final_df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_df")

query = """select *, ST_LineStringFromText(final_df.geometry, ',') as linestring from final_df"""

final_df = spark.sql(query)
final_df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `st_point`, `st_makeline` and `st_aswkt` from the Mosaic library (see [documentation](https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/geometry-constructors.html)).
This will give you the LineString in Well Known Text (WKT) format (as was asked in the question).

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import mosaic

# Create the PySpark DataFrame
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1,45,5],
        [1,45,6],
        [1,45,7],
        [2,46,5],
        [2,46,6],
        [2,46,7],
    ],
    columns=["trajectory_id", "latitude", "longitude"]
)
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
```

```
# Create LineString column
final_df = (
    spark_df
    .withColumn("longitude", F.col("longitude").cast(T.DoubleType()))
    .withColumn("latitude", F.col("latitude").cast(T.DoubleType()))
    .withColumn("point", mosaic.st_point(F.col("longitude"), F.col("latitude")))
    
    .groupBy("trajectory_id")
    .agg(F.collect_list(F.col("point")).alias("list_of_points"))
    
    .withColumn("linestring_geom", mosaic.st_makeline("list_of_points"))
    .withColumn("linestring", mosaic.st_aswkt("linestring_geom"))
    
    .select("trajectory_id", "linestring")
)
```

Note that `collect_list` does not guarantee to keep the same ordering of points (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable#:%7E:text=using%20collect_list%20together%20with%20groupBy%20will%20result%20in%20an%20unordered%20list%20of%20values)).

To keep the correct ordering of points, you can use the following:

```
# Create LineString column
final_df = (
    spark_df
    .withColumn("longitude", F.col("longitude").cast(T.DoubleType()))
    .withColumn("latitude", F.col("latitude").cast(T.DoubleType()))
    .withColumn("point", mosaic.st_point(F.col("longitude"), F.col("latitude")))

    .withColumn("point_id", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    .withColumn("list_of_points", F.collect_list("point").over(
        Window.partitionBy("trajectory_id").orderBy("point_id")
    ))
    .withColumn("max_point_id", F.max("point_id").over(
        Window.partitionBy("trajectory_id")
    ))
    .where(F.col("point_id") == F.col("max_point_id"))
    
    .withColumn("linestring_geom", mosaic.st_makeline("list_of_points"))
    .withColumn("linestring", mosaic.st_aswkt("linestring_geom"))
    
    .select("trajectory_id", "linestring")
)
```