# how to group by week number and show 3 weeks data in a tuple?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi guys i wanted to change this in pyspark dataframe

```
| player_id | stat_week|moves|week_num|
|1          |2022-06-13|    1|      24|
|1          |2022-06-06|   20|      23|
|1          |2022-06-20|    0|      25|
|2          |2022-06-06|   20|      23|
|2          |2022-06-13|    0|      24|
|2          |2022-06-20|    0|      25|
|1          |2022-05-30|   10|      22|
|1          |2022-05-23|   20|      21|
|1          |2022-05-16|   20|      20|
```

into

```
| player_id |moves     |week_num   | group by
|1          |(20,20,10)|(20,21,22) |    1
|1          |(20,1,0). |(23,24,25) |    2
|2          |(20,0,0). |(23,24,25) |    1
```

how can i do to group 3 weeks data and aggregate them as tuple ?

any help appreciated~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no python `tuple` data structure in `pyspark` with immutable feature and multiple data types, you need to write your own data type in pyspark. If you just want to collect the element in array-like data type, you can use `ArrayType` in pyspark.

You can create a week_num reference dataframe and then join back to your dataframe to do the grouping:

```
week_lst = [int(row['week_num']) for row in df.select('week_num').distinct().orderBy('week_num').collect()]
group_lst = [j//3 for j in range(len(week_lst))]
week_reference = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[(week, group) for week, group in zip(week_lst, group_lst)],
    schema=['week_num', 'group']
)
df = df.join(week_reference, on='week_num', how='left')
```

Then you can do your grouping by:

```
df.groupby('player_id', 'group')\
    .agg(collect_list('moves').alias('moves'),
         collect_list('week_num').alias('week_num'))
```

If you want to follow the order in the array, you can check this post: [collect_list by preserving order based on another variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580253/collect-list-by-preserving-order-based-on-another-variable)

Comment: This is awesome <3 thank you so much you save my day ~~